# Remove Duplicate Entries in a C++ Vector

Tags: c++, vector, duplicates, erase

Just want to remove duplicates. Pool is `vector<pair<string, int>>` but I seem to miss some elements at the start of the vector somehow. Can anyone verify the logic of the removal? Thanks :)

```
Pool Master::eliminateDuplicates(Pool generation)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < generation.size(); i++)
    {
        string current = generation.at(i).first;

        for(int j = i; j < generation.size(); j++)
        {
            if(j == i)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                string temp = generation.at(j).first;
                if(current.compare(temp) == 0)
                {
                    Pool::iterator iter = generation.begin() + j;
                    generation.erase(iter);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return generation;
}
```

Comment: Do you mind if it gets sorted?

Comment: An easier (and likely faster way than the `O(n^2)` way that it currently takes) of doing this is adding all the elements to a `std::set` and then back to a `std::vector`.

Comment: Also, I assume you mean `Pool` is a `vector<pair<string, int>>`?

Comment: I thought sets would only work based on the integer data type? I'm comparing for string duplicates.

EDIT yes, sorry typo ;)

Comment: Is this statement if(j == i){continue;} necessary? You can just start the loop from i+1.

Comment: @QuaziMarufurRahman Could result in a segmentation fault if i was the last element.

Comment: `std::set` works based upon either `operator<`, or you can give it a comparison function it can use. It'd be a pretty useless set if it only worked on integers!

Comment: In any case, you don't have to use set. You can sort your vector, and use `std::unque`. That would be O(Nlog(N))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very common issue.

Because after you erase an element the position j pointed will skip one element due to the j++ on the for loop.
the easiest solution to solve the problem based on your code is to add j-- after generation.erase(iter):

```
  generation.erase(iter);
  j--;
```

Answer (score 24):

If you don't mind sorting the vector, then you can use [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique). That would be O(Nlog(N))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,1,2,3,3,4,5,4,5,6,7};
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end()); 
    auto last = std::unique(v.begin(), v.end());
    v.erase(last, v.end());
    for (const auto& i : v)
      std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 Someone should write a wiki / FAQ entry for all the bread and butter vector usages.

Comment: @rhalbersma, SO should maintain a list of the most commonly asked questions on popular topics, like Top 10 C++ Questions or something. That would be handy. :D

Comment: I wonder why in all the answers about using `std::unique` nobody seems worth to mention that `unique` does not consider the last element.

Comment: @tomi.lee.jones I don't really understand what you mean here. `std::unique`'s behaviour seems quite intuitive to me.

Comment: @juan from the documentation, "removes all consecutive duplicate elements from the range [first, last)", so (1,2,3,1) will be (1,2,3,1). How is that intuitive? I know why the range is right-open and why it must be, but unless you are sure there is no dupe on the last position, unique seems useless.

Comment: @tomi.lee.jones Because all standard library algorithms work on open ranges, and usually we pass begin, end, which is open in that way.

Comment: If you are going to sort, why not `std::sort`?