# how to elminate the "doubled" elements of a vector in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, vector

I'm using the `HoughLines`to detect line in a frame, the lines information are saved in a `cv::vector<cv::Vec2f>`  which I handle as two dimensional array, I'm interested  in the second one , it the angle of the line, I want to keep only the lines that have a angle difference greater than `1.5 rad`  for that here I what I did :

```
.............................
cv::vector<cv::Vec2f> lineQ;
..............................

  // ordring the vector based on the angle value in rad 
for ( int i = 0 ; i< lineQ.size()-1; i++){
                for(int j= i+1;j<lineQ.size();j++){
                        if(lineQ[i][1] > lineQ[j][1]){
                            tmp = lineQ[i];
                            lineQ[i] = lineQ[j];
                            lineQ[j] = tmp;
                        }           
                }
            }
```

now I want to compare the vector elements between each other based on the angle

```
cv::vector<cv::Vec2f> line;
for ( int i = 0 ; i< lineQ.size()-1; i++){
                for ( int j= i+1; j<lineQ.size(); j++){
            if(fabs(lineQ[i][1] - lineQ[j][1])>1.5){
                        line.push_back(lineQ[i]);

                        }
                }
            }
```

this works for 2 lines but when I got 3  whit let's say 1.3rad as an angle  the size of  **line**
 is than 2. I though to use `erase`  but this change the size of my vector !

Comment: See if this helps  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16476207/2648826

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Duplicate Entries in a C++ Vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476099/remove-duplicate-entries-in-a-c-vector)

Comment: the problem that got with erase is that I only want to compare it based on the second dimension !

Comment: @TomekSzpakowicz  no it's not !

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. Can you give an example input and expected output data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to supply a soft "equals" to `std::unique_copy`:

```
std::unique_copy(lineQ.begin(), lineQ.end(), std::back_inserter(line),
                 [](const cv::Vec2f & a, const cv::Vec2f & b) {
                     return b[1] - a[1] <= 1.5;
                 });
```

Sidenote: You can also avoid the effort of writing your own sort (Bubble sort is just about the worst choice.) and use the standard library. Something like this ought to work:

```
std::sort(lineQ.begin(), lineQ.end(),
          [](const cv::Vec2f & a, const cv::Vec2f & b) {
              return a[1] < b[1];
          })).
```

(The above code assumes C++11, which most of us have by now. If you're stuck on an earlier version, you can write a couple of functor classes instead.)

Comment: what do you mean with return b[1] - a[1]    ? what does the 1 mean ?

Comment: @Engine: `a` and `b` correspond to `lineQ[i]` and `lineQ[j]` (sort of). Since you wrote `lineQ[i][1]`, I assumed that element one of each vector contains the sorting/matching key.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help ! just for understanding the function what does the [] before ( const ...) mean  ?

Comment: @Engine: It's the syntax for a C++11 lambda (aka anonymous function). It's a bit like declaring a function `bool Vec2f_approx_eq(const cv::Vec2f & a, const cv::Vec2f & b) { return …; }` at file scope and then passing it in as the predicate: `std::unique_copy(…, Vec2f_approx_eq);`. Obviously, the lambda is much cleaner because it let you keep everything in one place.

Comment: can you take a look on this question :   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017281/angle-difference-between-lines-in-opencv

Comment: @Engine: My pleasure, but please be aware that comments are for commenting on questions or answers, not for contacting people.